# Python: List index out of range in while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

**What I am trying to do**

I have this hashtable which I am trying to double hash the value however i am getting the error

```
if hashtable_list[hashKey] == None:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I have been at this for hours and can't seem to find where I am going wrong with this double hashing algorithm. Please can someone help me . Any help will be much appreciated from the bottom of my heart

```
# The HashParent class is the main class and follows an ADT
# in which it holds the key and value

class HashParent:

    def __init__(self, key, value):
        self.key = key
        self.value = value
        self.isItemDeleted = False

class HashTable(object):
    """
        a basic, minimal implementation of a hash map
    """
    def __init__(self):
        """
            constructs a new Map
        """
        #Create a table size of 4 None values eg [None, None, None, None]
        self.table = [None] * 4
        self.hashTableSize = 0

    #Uses Linear Probing to hash values into the table
    def __get_hash_code(self, key, value):
        return (hash(key) + value) % len(self.table)

    # Uses Linear Probing to hash values into the table
    def hashUsingQudratic(self, key, value):
        return (hash(key) + value ** 2) % len(self.table)

    def double_hashing(self, key, value):
        hashtable_size = self.hashTableSize
        hashtable_list = self.table
        hashKey = hash(key)
        if hashtable_list[hashKey] == None:
            hashtable_list[hashKey] = key
        else:
            new_hashkey = hashKey
            while hashtable_list[new_hashkey] is not None:
                steps = value - (key % value)
                new_hashkey = (new_hashkey + steps) % hashtable_size
            hashtable_list[new_hashkey] = key
        return hashtable_list

    def getitem(self, key):
        """
            gets the value associated with the key
        """
        hashTableLength = len(self.table)
        for i in range(hashTableLength):
            index = self.__get_hash_code(key, i)

            if self.table[index] !=  None:
                if self.table[index].key == key:
                    if self.table[index].isItemDeleted:
                        raise KeyError('Key is not in the map')
                    else:
                        return self.table[index].value

            elif self.table[index] is None:
                raise KeyError('Key is not in the map')

        raise KeyError('Hmm something has gone wrong here')

    def whichMethod(self, whichType, key,i):
        if whichType == 'linear':
            index = self.__get_hash_code(key, i)
            return index
        if whichType == 'quadratic':
            index = self.hashUsingQudratic(key, i)
            return index
        if whichType == 'double':
            index = self.double_hashing(key, i)
            return index


    def putItem(self, key, item, whichType):
        """
            stores the key value combo in the table
            implements open addressing collision resolution
        """
        parent = HashParent(key, item)
        for i in range(len(self.table)):
            index = self.whichMethod(whichType,key,i)

            if self.table[index] is None or self.table[index].isItemDeleted:
                self.table[index] = parent
                self.hashTableSize += 1
                break




    def deleteValue(self, key):
        """
            deletes a value from the hash table
        """
        hashTableLength = len(self.table)
        for i in range(hashTableLength):
            index = self.__get_hash_code(key, i)

            if self.table[index] != None:
                if self.table[index].key == key:
                    if self.table[index].isItemDeleted:
                        raise KeyError('Key is not in the map')
                    else:
                        self.table[index].isItemDeleted = True
                        self.hashTableSize -= 1
                        break

m = HashTable()
linear = 'linear'
quadratic = 'quadratic'
doubleHash = 'double'

m.putItem('first', 1,doubleHash)
m.putItem('ninth',9 ,doubleHash)
m.putItem('third', 3,doubleHash)
m.putItem('Tenth', 10,doubleHash)
print("The value at key 'ninth' is:" ,m.getitem('ninth'))

m.deleteValue('Tenth')
#Size should now be 3
print('The Hashatble size is:',m.hashTableSize)
```

Comment: That's not in the `while` loop; that's before it. And apparently your hashtable isn't at least `hashKey`-many elements long.

Comment: You don't appear to ever increase the size of `self.table`, so how would it be able to hold an index indicated by an arbitrary hash? Indexing into a list doesn't create slots that didn't exist before like it does in Javascript.

Comment: @Carcigenicate How would I go about doing this , do you mind posting an answer to help me and others who may face this issue

Comment: That's not straightforward. The hash can be huge, so you'd either need to restrict it in a way that doesn't cause excessive collisions, or have a list large enough to hold every possible hash (massive, would probably exhaust the memory of your computer).

Comment: @Carcigenicate How would I handle the collisons because that is the main aim of what I am trying to do

Comment: "Buckets" are the typical solution. In the case of a collision, place all colliding elements in a list at that slot, then on a lookup, do a linear search through the bucket to find the correct element.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so you do `m.putItem('first', 1, doubleHash)`, so `key` is `"first"`.
You pass `key` from `putItem` to `whichMethod`, then from `whichMethod` to `double_hashing`.

Then, `double_hashing` does this:

```
hashtable_list = self.table
```

`self.table` starts out as `self.table = [None] * 4`. It just has four `None`s. So `hashtable_list` will be `[None, None, None, None]`.

Then, it does:

```
hashKey = hash(key)
if hashtable_list[hashKey] == None:
```

`hash` returns an integer, and `key` is `"first"`. Let's just try that in the interpreter:

```
>>> hash("first")
-4954399314613441385
>>>
```

So, `hashtable_list[hashKey]` is like saying `[None, None, None, None][hash("first")]`, which is like saying `[None, None, None, None][-4954399314613441385]`. There's your `IndexError`.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I understand the index error now but I don't know how to modify my code to fix for this issue . Please could you show me how to implement your descriptive explanation

Comment: @DilhanBhagat Sorry, but I have no idea what your code is supposed to do, so I can't help you fix it.

Comment: I am just trying to implement a hashtable using all 3 probing techniques